# Ng-Show is not working properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mean-stack

```
$scope.stay = function() {
    alert("Inside Keep me In")
    $scope.timed = false;
    $scope.isLogStatus = true;
}

$scope.displayAlert = function() {
    $scope.timed = true;
    alert("inside display")
}

function idleTimer() {
    var t;
    $window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    $window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    $window.onclick = resetTimer; // catches mouse clicks
    $window.onscroll = resetTimer;
    //window.reload=$scope.stay();   // catches scrolling
    // window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

    function logout() {
        //Adapt to actual logout script
        $scope.displayAlert();
        alert('insinde logout');
        //  delete $window.localStorage.user;
        //  location.href="/";
    }

    function reload() {
        $window.location = self.location.href; //Reloads the current page
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        alert("timer reset")
        clearTimeout(t);
        // t = setTimeout(logout, 600000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
        $timeout(function() {
            alert("timout triggered");
            $scope.displayAlert();
        }, 9000); // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
    }
}
idleTimer();
```

I am using above html and in default if I keep

```
$scope.timed=true;
```

it's working
and when I click logged in I am doing

```
 $scope.timed=false;
```

and again if time is more than 10 minutes I am doing

```
$scope.timed=true;
```

(which is not triggering ng-show)
then show is not working

this is controller what is happening

```
$scope.stay = function() {
    alert("Inside Keep me In")
    $scope.timed = false;
    $scope.isLogStatus = true;
}

$scope.displayAlert = function() {
    $scope.timed = true;
    alert("inside display")

}

function idleTimer() {
    var t;

    window.onmousemove = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches mouse movements
    window.onclick = resetTimer; // catches mouse clicks
    window.onscroll = resetTimer;
    //window.reload=$scope.stay();   // catches scrolling
    // window.onkeypress = resetTimer;  //catches keyboard actions

    function logout() {
        //Adapt to actual logout script
        $scope.displayAlert();
        alert('insinde logout');
        //  delete $window.localStorage.user;
        //  location.href="/";
    }

    function reload() {
        window.location = self.location.href; //Reloads the current page
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        // alert("timer reset")
        clearTimeout(t);
        // t = setTimeout(logout, 600000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
        t = setTimeout(logout, 9000); // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
    }
}
idleTimer();
// Get the topbar menu
$scope.menu = Menus.getMenu('topbar');
```

Comment: Please add code that calls toggles `timed`

Comment: Okay, I have added that please check. @NikhilAggarwal

Comment: try using [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: actually timeout is working, alert is also being displayed but scope.timed is not showing @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are calling `logout` function. You are calling it via outside the angular framework which means that angular will not run the **digest cycle** and hence any change in **scope** will not be reflected to the **view**.

To verify, you can wrap the code in logout function with `$timeout`. Please do not forget to add it in the `dependencies`.

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.displayAlert();
});
```

Ideally, you should use `angular wrappers` e.g. `$window` for `window` and `$timeout` for `setTimeout`. By doing so angular, automatically, watches for the change and run digest cycle accordingly.

Comment: @srikanthnaidu - Can you replicate this issue somewhere where I can debug?

Comment: function resetTimer() {
     // alert("timer reset")
          clearTimeout(t);
         // t = setTimeout(logout, 600000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
         t= $timeout(function(){
          $scope.displayAlert();
       }, 9000);  // time is in milliseconds (1000 is 1 second)
      }

Comment: @srikanthnaidu - With this did you also changed `window` to `$window`

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: It should work. Here is a working example - http://next.plnkr.co/edit/LkpliyTWwoVumXnv?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: I have edited with modified code changes you gave still it's not working

Comment: @srikanthnaidu - Then there is some problem elsewhere. Can you please replicate the error somewhere?

Comment: Nikhil, I found the error, it's from my side, after I fixed it, your solution worked for me, thank you

Comment: @srikanthnaidu - No worries. Glad to help you :)